# make custom ui for light switch

Tags: java, android, user-interface

yo guys ... I want to make a light switch on layout as a **switch api** in android like this :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfUZU.png)
I have come across **toggle buttons** which is so similar to switches .
but I don't want to use toggle buttons .
Is this possible to change the layout of switch like this?
how to make it ?

Am I supposed to make an android API like [this](https://github.com/bitvale/PacButton) ? 
 I have tried to use lottie animations , standard JAVA animations(like TranslateAnimation) and gif for making this button, but I'm still confused about the road map for making it

Comment: do you need image based switch button right

Comment: yes i need image/gif based switch like this : 
https://dribbble.com/shots/2444868-Japanese-Switch,   https://dribbble.com/shots/11995836-VR-Switch and https://dribbble.com/shots/6188378-Light-switch-study

Comment: try below answer , in answer first option github library  works as exactly you expected. you can also try second method .

Answer (score 0):

1. **use github library** -   with dependency implementation

'com.github.GwonHyeok:StickySwitch:0.0.16'

```
<io.ghyeok.stickyswitch.widget.StickySwitch
        android:id="@+id/sticky_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:ss_animationDuration="600"
        app:ss_iconPadding="18dp"
        app:ss_iconSize="22dp"
        app:ss_leftIcon="@drawable/ic_male"
        app:ss_leftText="Male"
        app:ss_rightIcon="@drawable/ic_female"
        app:ss_rightText="Female"
        app:ss_selectedTextSize="14sp"
        app:ss_sliderBackgroundColor="@color/colorSliderBackground"
        app:ss_switchColor="@color/colorSwitchColor"
        app:ss_textColor="@color/colorTextColor"
        app:ss_textSize="12sp" 
        app:ss_animationType="line"/>
```

other way,

2. **create drawable image with xml**

create toggle.xml in res/drawable

add your favorite on and off image in drawble folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

apply the selector to your toggle button

```
<ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/chkState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""/>
```

for removing the text i used following in above code

```
textOff=""
textOn=""
```

if you any query please comment